# Parse 2 numbers in C# divided by minus sign

Tags: c#, string-parsing

I have to parse a string. It contains one or two numbers.

It can has 3 froms.

1. {number1}-{number2}
2. {number1}-
3. -{number2}

The numbers can be negative.

So for example:

- 100-200 means: number1 = 100, number2 = 200
- -100 means: number1 = null, number2 = 100
- 200- means: number1 = 200, number2 = null

now the harder part:

- -100-200 means: number1 = -100, number2 = 200
- -100- means: number1 = -100, number2 = null
- --100 means: number1 = null, number2 = -100
- 100--200 means: number1 = 100, number2 = -200
- -100--200 means: number1 = -100, number2 = -200
- -100-200- means: throw new FormatException(). its not a valid string.

Anything that cannot be parsed as 2 ints throws a formatexception (int.Parse does this, so it can be depended on).

I need a parser to parse it to two int? -s (nullable ints).

Every string is either valid (it makes sense), or invalid (it does not makes sense). There is no string that can mean 2 things (at least I didn't find one).

If I het the 2 value, I want it to return in a tuple.

I get tangled up in the ifs.

Comment: Sounds like you've defined a bunch of the tests.  Now have you _written_ these tests?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question correctly, but no. Only this structure is defined. I have not written tests.

Comment: can you show the actual code if you want nullable integer for example you can do the following int? myInt;

Comment: @SoonDead:  You have 9 tests defined in this question.  Are you not familiar with TDD?

Comment: Is this Homework? If it is add the Homework tag so that you get the right kind of help

Comment: Oh dear, so - is both minus and the delimiter.

Comment: @Bronumski this is not homework, but real work.

Comment: Is your fourth "harder" example correct?  It looks like "100--200" should parse to 100, -200.

Comment: @user92546: true I made a mistake there, corrected.

Comment: @SoonDead - This is real work, seriously, how about providing us what you have attempted.

Comment: @Ramhound : since I have only written about 4 ifs, and was not sure about the rest of them, I thought providing a definition of the problem is nearly as useful.

Comment: @AustinSalonen If you are referring to my examples of expected input-outputs in the question, then yes these were written by me, just to clarify the question. I have also tested the accepted answer against these.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(*Editing to add the updated regex from the comments*)

It seems like you could use the Regex class to figure this out, since your syntax is fairly regular and structures:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^(?<first>-?[\d.,]+)?-(?<second>-?[\d.,]+)?$");
var match = regex.Match(input);
if (match.Success)
{
  int? a = match.Groups["first"].Success
    ? Int32.Parse(match.Groups["first"].Value) 
    : (int?)null;

  int? b = match.Groups["second"].Success
    ? Int32.Parse(match.Groups["second"].Value) 
    : (int?)null;
}
```

Comment: This is great! I'll also need to parse decimals, which are culture invariant (so I can expect 5.02 but also 10,5). Can you help escaping these 2 characters too?

Comment: @SoonDead: Regex(@"^(?<first>-?[\d\.\,]+)?-(?<second>-?[\d\.\,]+)?$")

Comment: I have learned a great deal about using regex in C# from this. Like named groups. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @mrbm: small nitpick: I don't think you need to escape `.` and `,` if inside `[]`. Not a mistake though...

Answer (score 6):

Have you considered using a regular expression?

```
^(-?\d+)?-(-?\d+)?$
```

Comment: Can you explain this a little more? If you can solve this with regular expressions and return the two int?-s, then it is great.

Comment: @SoonDead: Have a look at the answer by Michael Edenfield. It's the same regular expression, but he also shows how to use it in C#.

Comment: @SoonDead you aren't going to get two int?s out of a regex -- it parses strings -- but once you get the string split into pieces it should be pretty easy from there.

Answer (score -2):

you could try .Split() method:

```
string testString = "100-200" ;

string[] results = testString.Split('-');

 int nr1;
 int nr2;
try
{
  nr1  = Convert.toInt32(results[0]);
  nr2  = Convert.toInt32(results[1]);
}
catch{}
```